# git - issue with ssh keys

Tags: git, macos, github

I've been getting this a lot and I've read through the error messages to try and resolve this. I'll delete my key on git and re-add this. However, I do notice I can correct this by simply rebooting my mac. But I don't want to do this every time I get the errors below. So what is the real problem? Why does a reboot of my machine fix this?  Is there something misconfigured? I'm running OSX El Capitan (10.11.1)

See this:

```
$ git pull origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (162.20.254.127)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kAUpJVGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdJACKviKwASSSY8.

    Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
    Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
    ERROR: Sorry, but @YourCompany has blocked access to SSH keys created by some third-party applications. Your key was created before GitHub tracked keys created by applications, so we need your help.

    If you personally created this key, you can approve it at:

      https://github.com/settings/ssh/audit/4586954/policy

    Otherwise, please upload a new key:

      http://git.io/KM0rtw

    Fingerprint: 03:aa:d6:43:a4:8d:37:fd:65:24:6c:95:78:67:51:65

    [EPOLICYKEYAGE]

    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Comment: @DanLowe you should consider turning that comment in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On GitHub, an organization has the ability to restrict third-party application access to their repositories. If these restrictions are activated, a number of things immediately happen. Among those things are:

> - SSH keys created before February 2014 immediately lose access to the organization's resources (this includes user and deploy keys).
> - SSH keys created by applications during or after February 2014 immediately lose access to the organization's resources.

The simplest way to fix this problem is to replace the old key with a new one.

You can read more about this [in GitHub's help](https://help.github.com/articles/about-third-party-application-restrictions/).

Comment: and add a passphrase.